# Test Multiple Conditions in Python Try statement

Tags: python, boto

I'm getting a list of aws ec2 instances with these command:

```
response = ec2.describe_instances()
for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
```

I need to see if each instance has a Private IP and a Public IP. If I use a try statement for both I get a syntax error:

```
try instance['PrivateIpAddress']  and instance['PublicIpAddress']:
```

This is the error:

```
File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 26
    try instance['PrivateIpAddress']  and instance['PublicIpAddress']:
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I use an if statement instead of a try, python complains that the key doesn't exist if the machine doesn't have a public ip:

```
if instance['PrivateIpAddress'] and instance['PublicIpAddress']:
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 26, in <module>
    if instance['PrivateIpAddress'] and instance['PublicIpAddress']:
KeyError: 'PublicIpAddress'
```

What's the right way to go about this?

Comment: `dict.get` will return the `item`, if it exists, otherwise `None`. And that is not how one use `try..except`. Please check the documentation

Comment: Other way to do this is using the keyword ´in´ such as ´if 'PublicIpAddress' in instance: ...´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check `if` the key is `in` the dictionary:

```
if 'PrivateIpAddress' in instance and 'PublicIpAddress' in instance:
```

Note, that this will just test whether those keys are present in the dictionary, but not if they have a meaningful value, e.g. depending on how you get your data they might be `None` or empty strings `""`. Alterantively, you could also use `get` to get the values, or `None` if they are not present.

```
if instance.get('PrivateIpAddress') and instance.get('PublicIpAddress'):
```

Here, the values are implicitly interpreted as `bool`, i.e. both `None` (or not-present) and empty string values would be considered `False`.

Comment: Thanks that works! But it breaks if the instance has neither a public ip or a private ip.

I use if for private and public ip. I use elif for just private ip. And I use else to capture if it has neither. But that doesn't work and I get:`KeyError: 'Public IP'` if that key doesn't exist. How can I test if that key doesn't exist?

Comment: @bluethundr Look like you are testing for `"PublicIpAddress"` and then try to access `"Public IP"`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sorry got confused before. :) Here's the current state of my code: [list ec2 instances](https://pastebin.com/KXgciN4C). I'm trying to account for stopped instances that have no public ip and no private ip. It gives an error when I run the script and it runs into that situation.

Answer (score 1):

`Try` statements are used for capturing various exceptions, such as the `KeyError`. You'd use them as such:

```
try:
    if instance['PrivateIpAddress'] and instance['PublicIpAddress']:
        # do something
except KeyError:
        # do something else
```